# ошибка при выполнении запроса к базе данных

Tags: php

Возникла ошибка при выполнении запроса к базе данных. Вот скрипт базы данных.

```
-- создание базы данных с условием
-- не забываем изменять название базы
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS zzz;
-- выбор текущей базы
-- не забываем изменять название базы
USE zzz;
-- создание таблицы с условием
-- не забываем изменять название таблиц
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
 id SERIAL,
 login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Вот файл index.php

```
<?php
$sql_server = 'localhost';
$sql_login = 'root';
$sql_password = '12345';

$sql_database = 'zzz';
$sql_table = 'test';

/*соединение с сервером базы данных (SQL сервер, SQL логин, SQL пароль)*/
$db = mysqli_connect($sql_server, $sql_login, $sql_password);
if(!$db) {
 exit('Error #1');
}

/*выбор базы данных (база SQL, переменная соединения)*/
mysqli_select_db($sql_database, $db);

/*запрос*/
$query = "SELECT login, password FROM $sql_table";

/*выполнение запроса и запись выполнения в переменную*/
$perform = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if(!$perform) {
 exit('Error #2');
}

/*результат, это ассоциативный массив*/
//$result = mysqli_fetch_array($perform) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($perform) or die(mysql_error());

if(!$result) {
 exit('Error #3');
}
?>
```

Ошибка **Error #2**
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Error description: No database selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вид функции:

```
mysqli_connect ( [string host [, string username [, string passwd [, string dbname [, int port [, string socket]]]]]] )
```

**Вам необходимо изменить:**

```
/*соединение с сервером базы данных (сервер, логин, пароль, база данных)*/
$db = mysqli_connect($sql_server, $sql_login, $sql_password);
if(!$db) {
 exit('Error #1');
}

/*выбор базы данных (база SQL, переменная соединения)*/
mysqli_select_db($sql_database, $db);
```

**на код:**

```
/*соединение с сервером базы данных (SQL сервер, SQL логин, SQL пароль)*/
$db = mysqli_connect($sql_server, $sql_login, $sql_password, $sql_database);
if(!$db) {
 exit('Error #1');
}

/*выбор базы данных (база SQL, переменная соединения)*/
#mysqli_select_db($sql_database, $db);
```

Comment: Alex! Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: Alex! Я нажимал, но моя репутация не позволяет. Там выводится такое сообщение.